# install rtorrent failed using yum install rtorrent in CentOS

Tags: centos, software-installation, bittorrent

I want to install `rtorrent` as a client (NOT SeedBox). I tried the following command:

```
yum install rtorrent
```

I get following message:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.iweb.ca
 * extras: centos.mirror.iweb.ca
 * updates: centos.mirror.netelligent.ca
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
No package rtorrent available.
Nothing to do
```

I think it's because I do not have rtorrent at my repository. What should I do to add rtorrent to my repository? I tried `yum update` without any success.

Answer (score 4):

Because you did not mention it, I am assuming you are on CentOS 5.

An old version of rtorrent can be found in the EPEL repository. I looked up the package [here](http://mirror.utexas.edu/epel/5Server/i386/) and found rtorrent version 0.7.8. The current version number is 0.8.7. The Fedora Project has instructions on installing the EPEL repository [here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#Using_EPEL%5d).

If you want the latest version, you will need to compile it from source from their website.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can't find it in the stock RPM repository that comes with CentOS is that rtorrent is traditionally a desktop application even though it is command line based. CentOS is a close of Red Had Enterprise Linux which does not include applications like rtorrent. A quick search online and I couldn't find any third party repositories for CentOS that included rtorrent.

My personal suggestion is to use Fedora, which is still based on the Red Hat architecture but includes a much wider range of packages including rtorrent.